# Error: Property 'defaultBinaryMessenger' cannot be accessed on 'ServicesBinding?' because it is potentially null

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to do a simple firebase app using flutter. I haven't started the firebase code yet. Just added the Firebase.initializeApp(). While running the below exception came and the program stopped.

```
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:148:52: Error: Property 'defaultBinaryMessenger' cannot be accessed on 'ServicesBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'ServicesBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/binding.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
      _binaryMessenger ?? ServicesBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger;
```

Below is my main.dart code:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: Login(),
  ));
}
```

Comment: on what platform?

Comment: @griffins flutter android